# Assigning button text and visible properties from DataGridView loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, datagridview

I cant get this code to work. I've tried multiple ways but i just dont seem to be getting any closer and running around in circles it feels like. Perhaps you guys can help me save my sanity.

So basically what i'm trying to do is this:

I have a DataGridView named DGV, I have 70 (I'm only showing the code for 5 as its repetitive) buttons each in its own cell on a tablelayout panel. What I'm trying to do is update the button.text name with each Cell value from my DGV. I'm only using the 1st column going down. Now it will never have more than 70 entries however sometimes it will have fewer. When it does I want the button to hide itself when there is no cell value (or the text is "").

```
Public Sub RefreshMatrix()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim DCC As String
    DCC = DGV.CurrentCell.Value
    Dim Dempty As String = Nothing
    Dempty = DGV(0, i).Value
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dempty) Then
         BtnA2.Visible = False
         i += 1
    Else
        BtnA2.Text = DGV.CurrentCell.Value
        BtnA2.Visible = True
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dempty) Then
        BtnA3.Visible = False
        i += 1
    Else
        BtnA3.Text = DGV.CurrentCell.Value
        BtnA3.Visible = True
        i += 1
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dempty) Then
        BtnA4.Visible = False
        i += 1
    Else
        BtnA4.Text = DGV.CurrentCell.Value
        BtnA4.Visible = True
        i += 1
    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dempty) Then
        BtnA5.Visible = False
        i += 1
    Else
        BtnA5.Text = DGV.CurrentCell.Value
        BtnA5.Visible = True
        i += 1
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Is the DGV manually populated or is there a DataSource?

Comment: All buttons currently draw (even if they have no cooresponding dgv cell value) and it repeats the first cell (0,0) for every button name rather than each a different one. What i want is for each button to have its own unique name from the DGV and if there is nothing in that cell such as "" or a null value then i want the button itself to button.visible = false. If there is a button text value then i want it to show itself and use that value as its button text

Comment: I am guessing that `RefreshMatrix` is called from the DGV loop mentioned in the title?

Comment: Yes, its a function that i call from a button i use on the main  mdi form where they all are on as one panel or another. Its a public function so it 'does something' just not the right thing. I'm a newbie, i'm not sure why Public Sub RefreshMatrix() and End Sub were omitted from the code window

Comment: `RefreshMatrix` is not a function - it doesnt return anything.  It is a Sub or void method...but it also is not needed.

Comment: First off thank you for taking the time in trying to help me. I've tried for the last few hours and I'm sorry to report that i'm just not following. If you can put that all together because i'm very confused. I'm using the sub as a function so i dont have to use the code each time on different buttons i have that will also do other things. As for the loop i cant convert what you wrote to what i have and get it working at the moment. I'm new to this but trying to learn by doing.

Comment: It would be better if you [edit] the post with what you have.  Are the buttons named as I guessed in the answer edit ("Btn" + {A - N} + {1 - 5})?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have generally made it much more complex than it needs to be.  The core problem is this:

```
BtnA2.Text = DGV.CurrentCell.Value
```

The `CurrentCell` has nothing to do with the current row or cell being iterated in your loop.  This is simpler:

```
' form level array for the buttons in order:
Private btns As Button()
```

In form load or at least after the form is built, populate it, listing the buttons in the order you want them used:

```
btns = {Button21, Button29, Button28...}
```

You might be able to load them from the TLP like this:

```
btns = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button).ToArray()
```

If the buttons were not added in the exact order you need to reference them, they wont be in the right order, so they need to be put in order:

```
btns = btns.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToArray()
```

This assumes that they are named: `"Btn" + {A - N} + {1 - 5}` (14 "rows" of alpha with 5 for each letter...I am guessing).  The good part is the loop.  This is all you need:

```
Dim text As String = ""
' To Do: add checks for 70 and test for IsNewRow maybe
For n As Int32 = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
    text = dgv1.Rows(n).Cells(1).Value.ToString

    btns(n).Text = text
    btns(n).Visible = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Trim)
Next
```

Or using a for each loop:

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
    If dr.IsNewRow Then Continue For

    text = dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString.Trim
    btns(n).Text = text
    btns(n).Visible = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
Next
```

---

When you find yourself writing long blocks of code that repeats except for one or 2 things, keep in mind the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) Principle. Stop and puzzle out a different solution.